# php5 and HTML Tidy - without compiling?

Tags: php5

I have an existing installation of PHP5 on my RHEL server.  It's managed via yum, so security updates are applied as usual.

I have need for HTML Tidy functionality, and was dismayed to learn that there (seemingly) is not a php5 extension available, and that (seemingly) the only way to get it is to compile php --with -tidy.   Zapping my yum-managed php installation and compiling just to get tidy functionality seems excessive.

Are there other methods for getting HTML Tidy integrated with php5 that I'm not finding?

---

Edited with answer:

Thanks to cyberx86 (from comments below) for the suggestion of enabling EPEL and grabbing the php-tidy package there.

Steps:

> [shell]# rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
>   [shell]# yum install php53-tidy.x86_64

Done and thanks.

Comment: If you don't have an objection to using the [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository (fully compatible with RHEL), it supplies the `php-tidy` extension which is probably what you need. The current version is compatible with PHP 5.3.3

Comment: That did the trick - added answer to question.  thanks.

Comment: @cyberx86 - please post what you have as an actual answer so that coder can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an objection to using the [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository (fully compatible with RHEL), it supplies the `php-tidy` extension which is probably what you need. The current version is compatible with PHP 5.3.3